# Methods Not Being Called to Main Method (Java)

Tags: java

I'm making a matchstick game for a class assignment & **required to use different methods aside from the main method.**

The player goes against the computer, can choose to pick 1-4 matches, and the computer has to always win.

Everything seemed fine on my IDE, except for the fact that I can't call the PLAYER() and COM() methods back to my main method. It prints with the following:

*Error:(25, 13) java: method PLAYER in class matchsticks cannot be applied to given types;
  required: int,java.lang.String,int
  found:    no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length*

Please help, thanks for reading. Here's my code:

```
public class matchsticks {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        String player;
        int match;
        int total = 0;

        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Welcome! RULES: ");
        System.out.println("The computer (COM) and player take turns picking up 1-4 matchsticks. There are 21 total.");
        System.out.println("The one who picks up the LAST matchstick loses. Ready to play?");

            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Name?: ");
            player = keyboard.next();



            // PLAYER method call to the main method. Not working.
            // Tried putting in parameters in () and didn't work.
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.print(player + "'s turn: ");
            match = keyboard.nextInt();
            PLAYER();


            //COMplay method call to main method. Not working.
            //Also tried putting parameters in () and it didn't help.
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.print("COM's turn: ");
            COMplay();

            //Loss output
            printLOSE(total);

    }

    //PLAYER//
    public static void PLAYER(int total, String player, int match) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (total < 21) {
            while (match > 4) {
                System.out.print("Nice try, but against the rules. Try again.");
                System.out.println(player+"'s turn: ");
                match = keyboard.nextInt();
            }
            total += match;

            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println(player+ "'s pick: " +match);
            System.out.println("Matches taken:  " +total);
            return;
        }
    }

    public static void COMplay(int match, int total) {
        if (match == 1) {
            total += 4;
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("COM's pick: 4");
            System.out.println("Matches taken:  " +total);
        }
        if (match == 2) {
            total += 3;
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("COM's pick: 3");
            System.out.println("Matches taken:  " +total);
        }
        if (match == 3) {
            total += 2;
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("COM's pick: 2");
            System.out.println("Matches taken:  " +total);
        }
        if (match == 4) {
            total += 1;
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("COM's pick: 1");
            System.out.println("Matches taken:  " +total);
        }
        return;
    }

    public static void printLOSE(int total) {
        if (total >= 21) {
            System.out.println("LOSE.");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Presumably there's a specific error when you attempt this... Something about not supplying the parameters your method is expecting...

Comment: @ David: Whoops, thanks for letting me know. It's updated with the error!

Comment: Man, I clowned myself. Fixed parameters and it worked, thanks man. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
PLAYER(total, player, match);

COMplay(match, total);
```

do you talk about this?. works to me, but you need a do-while cycle to complete your game. Bc you only got one chance to pick a matchsticks and isn't enough

**EDIT**

```
    public static void COMplay(int match, int total) {
    switch(match) {
        case 1: 
            total += 4;
            System.out.println("\nCOM's pick: 4");
            break;

        case 2:
            total += 3;
            System.out.println("\\nCOM's pick: 3");
            break;

        case 3:
            total += 2;
            System.out.println("\nCOM's pick: 2");
            break;

        case 4:
            total += 1;
            System.out.println("\nCOM's pick: 1");
        break;

        default:// nothing to do here.
    }

    System.out.println("Matches taken:  " +total);
    // You dont need a return statement
}
```

Its easy to read by this way